# Codeigniter e .htaccess em subpasta no servidor

Tags: php, codeigniter

Meu objetivo é fazer uma aplicação escrita em Codeigniter rodar no servidor em uma subpasta e não no domínio principal, exemplo: `www.dominio.com.br/foo`.

**O erro é sobre redirecionamento**, toda requisição está sendo redirecionada para a home (`www.dominio.com.br`).

Conteúdo do arquivo `www.dominio.com.br/foo/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Trecho do arquivo `www.dominio.com.br/foo/application/config/config.php`:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.dominio.com.br/foo/';
...
$config['index_page'] = '/index.php';
```

Adianto que já tentei utilizar o **RewriteBase** dessa forma...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

...mas tb não tive sucesso.

Confesso tb que alterei o .htaccess de tudo quanto é forma e sempre redireciona para a home.

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Essa `/` no início do seu `RewriteRule` (*/index.php*), não está fazendo direcionar para a raiz do seu servidor? O `.htaccess` original do *Codeigniter* não tem esta barra.

Comment: Sem a `/` tb não funciona! Obg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou definir o caminho correto para `RewriteRule`.

Note que você especificou `RewriteBase`, porém, `RewriteRule` continua apontando para a raíz.

Para resolver, faça isso: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.php/$1 [L]`

Exemplo completo:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Algumas observações**

1. O nome `index.php` é desnecessário caso `DirectoryIndex` já esteja apontando para o mesmo.
2. Quando aplicar num diretório root, é boa prática especificar a base `RewriteBase /`.

**Alternativa**

Alternativamente, uma forma mais simplificada para as regras HTACCESS:

Para diretório raíz/root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Para um subfolder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foo/
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) /foo/
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você colocou seu CI com a estrutura padrão dentro da pasta FOO não tem porque ele não funcionar.
O que parece é que sua base para a escrita está em outra pasta.
Experimente esse padrão abaixo; dentro da sua pasta na memsa hierarquia do application.

```
'<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>'
```

Isso deve funcionar!

Answer (score 0):

Algumas considerações que talvez possam te ajudar:

1. Se você utiliza a abordagem MVC, principalmente a VC, tendo um controller `foo` e nele a função `index()` chamando a view desejada, funcionaria da forma que você quer.
2. O CodeIgniter permite trabalhar com as rotas de sua url pelo arquivo `routes.php`:

   ```
   $route['bar'] = 'foo';  // rota foo para o controller bar
   ```
3. As chamadas de views podem ser feitas também dentro de pastas: Ex: `$this->load->view('pasta/arquivoPhp')`;

Obs: Costumo deixar o `$config['base_url'] = '';` e `$config['index_page'] = '';` vazios ou no `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.dominio.com.br/foo';` sem a última barra.

Answer (score 0):

Costumo deixar meu `application/config/config.php` assim:

```
$config['base_url'] = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") ? "https" : "http");
$config['base_url'].= "://" . (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : "");
$config['base_url'].= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

$config['index_page'] = '';
```

e o meu `.htaccesss` assim:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

e não costumo ter nenhum problema em deixar em subpastas como no seu caso que precisa, que por sinal sempre deixo assim para fazer um testes.