# subpasta de desenvolvimento codeigniter não funciona

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess

bom dia.
Estou fazendo manutenção em um back-end PHP que utiliza o framework codeigniter. Para testar os novos códigos, criei uma subpasta no sistema (testing) e copiei os arquivos do diretório principal para subpasta.

Olhando o tutorial [Codeigniter e .htaccess em subpasta no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59930/codeigniter-e-htaccess-em-subpasta-no-servidor), percebi que deveria reescrever os arquivos config e .htaccess na subpasta. Entretanto, não obtive sucesso.

Abaixo, as fotos dos arquivos originais do sistema, que estão encontrados atualmente no root e quando eu copiei para subasta, ele exibe uma tela em branco, sem retorno. Na original, {"response":{"data":[],"status":"0","error_code":"16","message":"Please send access key!"}}

Poderiam me ajudar com essa adaptação? Geralmente eu faço uma copia para o meu servidor de testes, ou localhost, mas preciso realizar chamadas HTTPs de um aplicativo nativo e a versão do PHP do sistema, é 5.2, meu servidor de testes é mínimo 5.4.

[image: application\config\config.php]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o teu problema está apenas no ficheiro de configs no qual deves definir o

```
$config['base_url'] = ENDERECO_BASE/PASTA_DE TESTE;
```